# How do fix :"Cannot read property 'init' of undefined TypeError"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using Jquery-3.2.1, Jquery-Ui 1.12.1.In my JavaScript file:

```
window.TruyenOnlineScript = (function () {
    var _this = {};

    _this.init = function () {
        _this.initSearchMobile();
        _this.initSidebar();
    };   

    _this.initSearchMobile = function () {
        //Open Input Search Mobile
        $('.js-open-search-box-mobile').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body').addClass('open-search-box');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#js-search-input-mobile').focus()
            }, 500);
        });
    };

    _this.initSidebar = function () {
        //Open Navbar Moblie
        $('.js-open-sidebar').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('body').addClass('open-sidebar');
        });
    };

})();

$('document').ready(function () {
    window.TruyenOnlineScript.init();
});
```

But I got the error "init of undefined":

[image]

Can anybody show me how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Your initialization function does not have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting `window.TruyenOnlineScript` to the return value of an Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
window.TruyenOnlineScript = (function () {
   . . .
})();
```

but that expression doesn't return any value and so `window.TruyenOnlineScript` winds up being `undefined` (and that's why you can't call `init()` on `undefined`).

**You need to have the IIFE return an object for `TruyenOnlineScript` to reference.**

```js
window.TruyenOnlineScript = (function () {
    var _this = {};

    _this.init = function () {
        _this.initSearchMobile();
        _this.initSidebar();
    };   

    _this.initSearchMobile = function () {
        //Open Input Search Mobile
        $('.js-open-search-box-mobile').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body').addClass('open-search-box');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#js-search-input-mobile').focus()
            }, 500);
        });
    };

    _this.initSidebar = function () {
        //Open Navbar Moblie
        $('.js-open-sidebar').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('body').addClass('open-sidebar');
        });
    };
    
    return _this; // <-- Now this will be returned

})();

$('document').ready(function () {
    window.TruyenOnlineScript.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just checked and saw the return _this.

Answer (score 1):

Some users have already given you the solution, but I want to show you another way to create the same object. I can't say it's "better", but it's clearer and a little easier to understand:

```js
window.TruyenOnlineScript = {
    init: function () {
        this.initSearchMobile();
        this.initSidebar();
    },

    initSearchMobile: function () {
        //Open Input Search Mobile
        $('.js-open-search-box-mobile').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body').addClass('open-search-box');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#js-search-input-mobile').focus()
            }, 500);
        });
    },

    initSidebar: function () {
        //Open Navbar Moblie
        $('.js-open-sidebar').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('body').addClass('open-sidebar');
        });
    }   
};
```